# Is there a way to filter items for the view without looping over them?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, entt

EnTT - https://github.com/skypjack/entt - is an ECS framework. Their examples show that you can make a view such as:

```
auto card_lot = registry.view < const Card, const Owner>();
```

Which would return all the entities assigned a Card or Owner component. However, I am wondering if it's possible to fine tune that view initializer to be more specific, such as :

```
auto card_lot = registry.view< const Card, const Owner == MAINPLAYER >();
```

Or similar, without having to loop through the items after initialization? Or is the performance of the loop so negligible that I shouldn't worry about fine-tuning outside a loop.

I tried to read the docs - https://skypjack.github.io/entt/md_docs_2md_2entity.html - but I couldn't see any related function.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to know that what you’re describing is a bottleneck?

Comment: yes, but I was still curious as to if there's a way to do it.